Is there an enum listing all JVM parameters?
I've been trying to find if there's an enum (or any other structure) listing all JVM parameters, for example javax.net.ssl.keyStore, or jdk.tls.server.protocols, something similar to the HttpStatus enum from Spring Boot.
Would anybody know of such a enum?
EDIT: To make thing more clear, I'm looking for an enum that's only listing the possible JVM property names, not their values. I know how to read the values but I just don't want to repeat the same string all the time when calling System.getProperty().

Potentially unlikely, as some of those parameters are retrieved at the callsite via System#getProperty(String) or similar, leaving the knowledge of the key to lookup to the caller/implementer. In this sense, there wouldn't be a single central location with all of them, but there are documentation pages from Oracle to that effect.

Thanks @Rogue. Yea, my application is configuring a bunch of other components and has multiple classes adding JVM parameters to external files. I can write my own enum for the properties that I'm using but wanted to make sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel again :-)

Not really an enum but mostly this shall help?

There isn't such a thing.

A system property is not a “JVM option”. As @Rogue said, these properties get a meaning by Java code calling System.getProperty(…) which any Java code can do, e.g. when my code calls System.getProperty("foo.bar.baz") and does something with the result, we have a new system property “foo.bar.baz” with a meaning depending on what my code does. So 1) the JVM is not involved at all and 2) the number of potentially existing system properties is infinite. Further, even for JDK code there are system properties which had a meaning in the past but are irrelevant today.


Is there an enum listing all JVM parameters?

There is no such thing.
Why?
(I'm going to assume that "JVM parameters" refers to command line JVM options or JVM system properties ... or both.)
The fundamental problem is that there are binary compatibility rules that apply when an enum definition is modified.  You can add new enum constants, but if you remove an existing constant, that is an incompatible change.  That means that code compiled against the old version cannot use the new version ... without recompilation.
Why is this a problem?
The Java platform is continually evolving.  New parameters are added, and existing parameters are obsoleted and (ultimately) removed.  For system properties, there is also the issue that the parameter could change from a JVM parameter to a parameter of a separate module and vice versa.  As a result, an enum that mirrored the current set of JVM parameters would introduce binary compatibility problems between Java versions (and even releases).
A second problem is that some parameters are undocumented and semi-internal.  Others depend on how the build options used when the JVM disto was built.  An enum class that accurately tracks the parameters available in >this< JVM would be difficult to implement.
What should you do?
Well you could declare your own enum ... but you would run into the problems above.  You could probably ignore the private and build-dependent parameters, but having different versions of the enum depending on the JVM version is still going to lead to difficulties.
Myself?  I would model the (current) set of system parameters as a HashSet<String> or a HashMap<String, Something>; i.e. don't try to model the parameters in the Java type system.  (The corollary is is that you would need to deal with certain things at runtime rather than compile time.)

Note that this is different to HTTP status.  The reason that Spring can define an enum for HTTP status codes is that they are specified (by W3C specs) and standard codes would never be removed from the enum.  But there would still be problems dealing with a web server that use non-standard codes; see Non-standard HTTP response codes: recommended client behaviour.
